# why function runtime_args can be express like this?

Tags: go

This code is in proc.go. I can not understand function runtime_args, can anyone help me? Sorry for my poor english.

```
// Args hold the command-line arguments, starting with the program name.
var Args []string

func init() {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        // Initialized in exec_windows.go.
        return
    }
    Args = runtime_args()
}

func runtime_args() []string // in package runtime

// Getuid returns the numeric user id of the caller.
//
// On Windows, it returns -1.
func Getuid() int { return syscall.Getuid() }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [`Go Programming Language Specification`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations):

> A function declaration may omit the body. Such a declaration provides the signature for a function implemented outside Go, such as an assembly routine.

In your case this function implementation is actually declared in the `runtime` package

[`proc.go`](https://golang.org/src/os/proc.go?s=434:486#L24):

```
...
func runtime_args() []string // in package runtime
...
```

[`runtime.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/runtime.go?s=1232:1355#L58):

```
...
//go:linkname os_runtime_args os.runtime_args
func os_runtime_args() []string { return append([]string{}, argslice...) }
...
```